# How to change value in view

Tags: angular

I'm try to change property `[options.arcDelimiters]="50"` in view.

this is my link to code [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6xho7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You really need to include the relevant code in the question. If you don't then the code you refer to may change, the link may eventually break, but more importantly; it requires much more effort to assist you.

What outcome do you have, and what outcome do you require?

Comment: each code be add in code sample for better readability and adding link to word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `arcDelimiters` inside `options`, like so ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-arc-delimiter-stackoverflow)) - it accepts an array of numbers from 0 to 100 ([angular-gauge-chart](https://github.com/recogizer/angular-gauge-chart)):

```
 // app.component.ts

 ngOnInit() {
  this.options = {
    arcDelimiters: [50],
    ...
 }
```

Comment: What does that mean for you to change the value from html ? With an input ?

Comment: @elhanan what's the purpose? you cannot add it in the way, you've specified. The component input consumes `options` object with all options. But you can change it from you app.component.ts.

Comment: this is original code in html
i get value from object cr_cont and i need to put value in property of chart

<div class="gauges" *ngFor="let cr of cr_count">
 <rg-gauge-chart
  [canvasWidth]="canvasWidth"
  [needleValue]=cr.op
  [bottomLabel]=cr.op
  [centralLabel]="centralLabel"
  [options]="options"
  [name]=op
  [bottomLabel]="bottomLabel">
 </rg-gauge-chart>

Comment: Create a function which would take `arcDelimiters` in arguments & return options 
with specified values and use `getOptions(cr.arcDelimiters)` in html. See here -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvzvkg